# Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined with jest fail on import of dependencies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to configure tests to run on my typescript application and I'm trying to write two tests for index.tsx and App.tsx.

The error that I'm getting is the following

FAIL src/**tests**/index.test.ts
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined

  3 |  */
  4 |
> 5 | import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
    | ^
  6 | import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
  7 | import {microAppReference} from '../index';
  8 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/es-abstract/2021/IsArray.js:8:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/es-abstract/2021/ArraySpeciesCreate.js:10:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/array.prototype.flat/implementation.js:3:26)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/array.prototype.flat/index.js:6:22)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/index.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/index.test.ts:5:1)
```

FAIL src/**tests**/App.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

  1 | import * as React from 'react';
> 2 | import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
    | ^
  3 | import Routes from "./routes";
  4 |
  5 | export default class App extends React.PureComponent {

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-router/Router.js:110:32)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-router-dom/Router.js:5:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-router-dom/BrowserRouter.js:19:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js:6:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/App.test.tsx:8:1)
```

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.484 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

The **App.test.tsx** looks like this

```js
import App from '../App'
import Enzyme, {mount} from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

function initApp() {
    const holderElement = document.createElement('div');
    holderElement.setAttribute('id', 'app-root');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0)?.appendChild(holderElement);

    return mount(
        <App/>, {attachTo:holderElement});
    }

describe('Application', () => {

    it('should render import home page', () => {

        const application = initApp();
        expect(application.find('.import-page-wrapper').length).toBe(1)
    });
});
```

The **index.test.ts** looks like

```js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {microAppReference} from '../index';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Index', () => {

    const wrapper = document.createElement('wrapper');
    const appRoot = document.createElement('root');

    wrapper.appendChild(appRoot);
    document.querySelector('body')?.appendChild(wrapper);

    const app = microAppReference(wrapper, appRoot);

    it('should launch and close the application', (done) => {

        // @ts-ignore
        app.launch();

        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(document.querySelectorAll('.import-page-wrapper').length).toBe(1);
            app.close();

            setTimeout(() => {
                expect(document.querySelectorAll('.import-page-wrapper').length).toBe(0);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**App.tsx** looks like

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./routes";

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Routes />
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and **index.tsx** looks like

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

export const microAppReference = function (appWrapper: HTMLElement, appRoot: HTMLElement) {
    return {
        launch: function (props: any) {
            ReactDOM.render(<App />, appRoot);
        },
        close: function () {
            ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(appRoot);
        }
    };
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
// @ts-ignore
window.microAppReference = microAppReference;
```

**jest.config.js** is the following:

```js
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    },
    automock: true,
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '.*/test-utils/.*',
        '.*/server/.*',
        '.*/plugins/.*'
    ],
    'coverageDirectory': './build/reports/test/coverage',
    'collectCoverageFrom': [
        'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
        '!src/**/*.d.ts',
        '!**/__tests__/**',
        '!**/3rd-party/**'
    ],
    'coverageThreshold': {
        'global': {
            'branches': 80,
            'functions': 80,
            'lines': 80,
            'statements': 80
        }
    },
};
```

It seems that it is not mocking or importing the dependencies.